# Why doesn't std::execution::par launch threads with std::views::iota iterators

Tags: c++, multithreading, libstdc++, std-ranges

Here are two version of the code. One uses `std::vector` iterators in the `std::for_each` call, the other uses the `std::views::iota` iterators.

I expect both of these to use multiple threads, since I'm using `std::execution::par`, but it appears like that isn't the case. The `iota` version only uses a single thread and I don't understand why.

## Vector version

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <ranges>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::mutex io_mutex;
   auto offsets0_ = std::views::iota(0, 8);
   auto offsets0 = std::vector<int>(std::begin(offsets0_), std::end(offsets0_));
   std::for_each(
      std::execution::par,
      std::begin(offsets0), std::end(offsets0),
      [&](auto offset0) {
         io_mutex.lock();
         std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << offset0 << '\n';

         // Emulate doing a bunch of work, otherwise threads don't spawn in either scenario
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
         io_mutex.unlock();
      });
}
```

### Output

```
139803706330688: 0
139803706330688: 1
139803695208000: 6
139803691009600: 5
139803699406400: 4
139803706330688: 2
139803695208000: 7
139803691009600: 3
```

So it used 4 threads to go through all items. My PC has 4 cores, so that makes sense.

## Iota ranges version

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <ranges>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::mutex io_mutex;
   auto offsets0 = std::views::iota(0, 8);
   std::for_each(
      std::execution::par,
      std::begin(offsets0), std::end(offsets0),
      [&](auto offset0) {
         io_mutex.lock();
         std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << offset0 << '\n';

         // Emulate doing a bunch of work, otherwise threads don't spawn in either scenario
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
         io_mutex.unlock();
      });
}
```

### output

```
139954983456320: 0
139954983456320: 1
139954983456320: 2
139954983456320: 3
139954983456320: 4
139954983456320: 5
139954983456320: 6
139954983456320: 7
```

With the iota ranges iterators it only a single thread.. Why? are ranges not supposed to be used like this?

Both of these were compiled with these options: `g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -ltbb -O3`. Using gcc 11.1.0, glibc 2.33, and tbb 2020.3.

Comment: I'm adding an answer with my findings, but I'm definitely still interested in better/more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

As per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), this is the signature of for_each with the execution policy parameter.

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIt, class UnaryFunction2 >
void for_each( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryFunction2 f );
```

Where `ForwardIt` should satisfy the LegacyForwardIterator requirements.

But `iota_view::iterator` only goes up to LegacyInputIterator when the `value_type` is 'incrementable', from my understanding it never satisfies `LegacyForwardIterator`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view/iterator)

This is probably why the `for_each` call doesn't do what you'd expect.

I'm not sure why it's not just a compilation error, maybe it's intentional, though it does feel unusual to completely ignore the execution policy. I hope another answer can shed light on this.